# Wirecloud 0.9.2 - NGSI Plugins

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I upgraded my WireCloud instance to version `0.9.2`, I installed many plugins but when I try to install **ngsi-type-browser v 1.0.0** and **ngsi-browser v 1.0.2** I get the following error:

> Error uploading the following components:
>   CoNWeT_ngsi-browser_1.0.2.wgt: Required feature (NGSI) is not enabled
>   for this WireCloud installation.

Can someone help me to figure out what I am missing?

How can I enable this `NGSI` feature? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `NGSI` feature is enabled by default. It's provided by the `wirecloud.fiware` Django app.

### How to check if the `wirecloud.fiware` app is active

Django apps are configured using the `settings.py` file. On a normal WireCloud installation you should see something similar to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    'wirecloud.oauth2provider',
    'wirecloud.fiware',
)
```

Check that the `wirecloud.fiware` app is listed in that list.

As the `settings.py` file is python code, the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting can be modified by other parts of the code. You can check that the final value of the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting contains the `wirecloud.fiware` app by running the following command from the WireCloud folder:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

This command should open a python console loading the django environment. Now you can check the final value of the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings by running the following command:

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings; print('wirecloud.fiware' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
True
```

This command should return `True`. You can get the full list of active apps by running this command instead:

```
In [2]: from django.conf import settings; print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
('django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'django.contrib.admin', 'wirecloud.commons', 'compressor', 'wirecloud.catalogue', 'wirecloud.platform', 'wirecloud.oauth2provider', 'wirecloud.fiware')
```